# How to remove a string from the list, by looking at a certain letter?

Tags: c#, string, list, letter

```
var countries = new List<string>() { "India", "Australia", "Austria", "Canada", "Mexico", "Japan" };
            foreach(string country in countries)
            {
                if (country.StartsWith("A"))
                {
                    countries.Remove(country);
                }
            }
            foreach (string country in countries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(country);
            }
```

For instance I would like to get rid of countries starting with the letter A

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `RemoveAll()` ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0)) which requires a condition to know if the element has to be removed or not

You could do :

```cs
// The List declaration you provided
var countries = new List<string>() { "India", "Australia", "Austria", "Canada", "Mexico", "Japan" };

// Replace your first `foreach(string country in countries)` with this line
countries.RemoveAll(country => country.StartsWith("A"));

// The way of displaying data you provided
foreach (string country in countries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(country);
}
```

Edit : As Johnathan Barclay said in the comments, "if you want to perform a case-insensitive search, you should provide a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_) rather than using `ToUpper()`", as I did in the uneditted answer.

The code would be :

```cs
// The List declaration you provided
var countries = new List<string>() { "India", "Australia", "Austria", "Canada", "Mexico", "Japan" };

// Replace your first `foreach(string country in countries)` with this line
countries.RemoveAll(country => country.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

// The way of displaying data you provided
foreach (string country in countries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(country);
}
```

Comment: you change the logic with `.ToUpper()`

Comment: @fubo the question is "to get rid of countries starting with the letter A" so I'm making sure that all countries with letter A are removed, sensibility of upper and lower cases hasn't been requested

Comment: If you want to perform a case-insensitive search, you should provide a [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_) rather than using `ToUpper()`.

Comment: (despite what the example on the MSDN page for `List<T>.RemoveAll` says)

Comment: Okay I'm adding this part in the answer thanks @fubo

Answer (score 1):

Approach with   [`RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0)

```
List<string> countries = new List<string>() { "India", "Australia", "Austria", "Canada", "Mexico", "Japan" };
countries.RemoveAll(country => country.StartsWith("A"));
countries.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Yeah RemoveAll will work, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use the `RemoveAll()` property to get the result you want.

```
var countries = new List<string>() { "India", "Australia", "Austria"};

countries.RemoveAll(Country=>country.StartsWith("A"))
```

Comment: This was covered by prior answers, which actually compiled (yours won't)